# List AWS services in use with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Is there a way for me to list all the services I'm using in AWS by terminal?

For example, all the s3 buckets, all the lambdas, so on so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by looking at [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/).

You might also search for [AWS inventory tools](http://%20https://www.google.com/search?q=aws%20inventory%20tools).